# Facebook Graph fetch user Photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch Display photo of the users from Facebook using the following url

> http://graph.facebook.com/harshamv/picture?type=large

is there any way i can download the title of the profile photo with a definite dimensions like 96*96 px.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: AllisonC: i have gone thru that.. but i quite didnt understand how to structure the URL call.

Comment: What programming language are you using to call this, php?

Comment: i am using PHP.. but serving the photo in the android client

Comment: Can you post the php code where you are making this call?

Comment: i am doing that in Android.. passing the above URL and doing the call..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try re-sizing the photo with css, or call for 'normal', 'small', 'square' after the picture?type=